# How to use default sorting in peewee meta class

Tags: python, peewee

I'm use Peewee ORM.

I have a class such as this:

```
class Sample(PMBaseModel):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    location = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = peewee.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sample'
```

how i can use `Meta Class` for set default ordering and define Order type?

Comment: I know to i should use `order_by` in `Meta class`, but i don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found answer, with thanks of @giaosudau.

```
class Sample(PMBaseModel):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    location = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = peewee.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sample'
        order_by = ['-location']
```

if use '-' in the first of field name in `order_by` section, peewee perform DESC ordering of filed.

Comment: Just to leave the SO updated this option is droped since version `3.0.0` http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/3.0.0/peewee/changes.html#model-meta-options

Answer (score 1):

Follow this instruction https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options

we use `order_by`   a list of fields to *use for default ordering*

Then

```
class Sample(PMBaseModel):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    location = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = peewee.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sample'
        order_by = ['location']
```

Comment: thanks alot, I want to define sort ordering!
in this case, peewee return sorted list as ascending!
how i can define sort type?